# Android 3.2 VideoView freezes, audio carries on

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I'm streaming HLS, and after 10 minutes or so, the video hangs but the audio stays on. I can then not click anything other than holding the home button to get the task manager to force close the app. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662100/need-help-creating-a-list-of-youtube-videos/11662792#11662792  check this link.